# How does a linearly polarized spin 1/2 wave look like?

Tags: waves, electrons, quantum-spin, spinors

Spin 1 waves are easy to illustrate and a linearly polarized spin 2 wave looks like [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gravitational_wave#/media/File:Quadrupol_Wave.gif), but what is the counterpart for a spin 1/2 wave?